# Calculate all points in an arc

Tags: ios, core-graphics, trigonometry, geometry

I am trying to draw lines from the center of a circle to points (x, y) in the circumference.

To calculate this the angle is used. I need to render points in between two angles. E.g. Angle 0 to angle 1 I would like to render lines from the center of the circle to 5 different points along the circumference between angle 0 and 1. There might be any number of points in between these two angles.

How can I calculate these 5 points? I would need to calculate the (x, y) using angle i and the (x, y) using angle i+1. and then get the arc between these two points.

How is this done and how would I then get the individual points within this arc so that I can incrementally draw lines from the center to these individual points?

Comment: umm.. get `(x,y)` using angle `i+0.2`, `i+0.4` and so on? Am I missing something?

Comment: I thought the angle should be of type int. I guess I was missing something :/

Comment: Why? `cos(0.1*M_PI/180)` is a valid value..